# Higher Moments, Probability

Tags: probability

$W$ is a random variable with $E[(W−μ)^3]=10$ and $E(W^3)=4$. Is it possible that $μ=2$?

Am I supposed to find the skewness?

Comment: Expand the product $(W-\mu)^{3}$ and use the linearity of expectation. Substitute in the given values, making sure to remember that the assumed value $\mu=2=E[W]$, and see if what results will admit a sensible solution.

Comment: You have not said whether $E[W]=\mu$ (though given Robert Israel's answer it may not matter).  If it is then you can find $E(W^2)=-36$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\mu > 0$, $(x-\mu)^3 < x^3$ for all real numbers $x$ (because $x^3$ is an increasing function of $x$).  What would that say about the relationship between $E[(W-\mu)^3]$ and $E[W^3]$?